# using prolog to generate sentences

Tags: prolog

Consider the following list of states:
    [Sin,S2,S3,...,Sout]

and following rules:

1. it is possible to go back from S(n) to S(n-1) if there is such
   S(n-1)
2. it is not possible to go back from S(out)
3. a sentence always begins with S(in) and ends with S(out)

I would like to have a rule that could be activated like this:

```
 ?- sentence(X, backs)
```

in which 'backs' means how many times a "back" is allowed.

For this list [a,b,c,d]

```
 ?- sentence(x, 2)
```

would generate:

```
[a,b,c,d] %no backs
[a,b,a,b,c,d] %one back
[a,b,c,b,c,d] %from d we cannot go back
[a,b,a,b,c,b,c,d] %two backs
[a,b,c,b,a,b,c,d] %two backs
```

Comment: Your problem, as currently stated, will return either 1 it the list has only two items or infinite otherwise. E.g. if it has 3 elements (a,b,c) you could form (a,b,c), (a,b,a,b,c), (a,b,a,b,a, ... ,c) where ... are any number of (b,a) subsequences.

Comment: There is constraint expected in the query. With the "backs" parameter I expect to control how many times to go back. That would make it finite.

Comment: so have you found any of the answers here helpful at all, worthy of an upvote and an accept?

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that seems to be working:

```
sentence( [A|B], N, [A|X]) :- B=[_|_] -> sentence(B,[A],N,X) 
                                      ;  B = X.
sentence( B, _, 0, B).                  % no more moves back left
sentence( [B,C], _, N, [B,C]):- N>0.    % no going back from end node
sentence( [B|C], A, N, [B|X]):- N>0, C=[_|_],             
                                sentence( C, [B|A], N, X).      $ fore
sentence( [B|C], [A|D], N, [B|X]):- N>0, C=[_|_], N1 is N-1, 
                                sentence( [A,B|C], D, N1, X).   $ aft
```

Running it gives me

```
23 ?- sentence([a,b,c,d],2,X).
X = [a, b, c, d] ;
X = [a, b, c, b, c, d] ;
X = [a, b, c, b, c, b, c, d] ;
X = [a, b, c, b, a, b, c, d] ;
X = [a, b, a, b, c, d] ;
X = [a, b, a, b, c, b, c, d] ;
X = [a, b, a, b, a, b, c, d] ;
No
```

Comment: @AdrianHerscu from your description it is unclear whether the move back from `S2` to `Sin` is allowed. Both my code and your example operate as if it were allowed. If not, just do `go([A|B], N, [A|B2]) :- sentence(B, N, B2).`